# HTML checkbox element not being passed value into jQuery and AJAX string

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui, checkbox

I have a simple HTML form with a few checkboxes. my goal here is to pass this data (value of checked boxes) to a jQuery function and input the values into a string that will be passed via Ajax to a php script. here is my html:

```
     <table class="ui-widget-content" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td width="252px;">PVC's Required</td>
                <td align="left">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pvc" name="pvc" value="abc" />abc<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pvc" name="pvc" value="def" />def<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pvc" name="pvc" value="ghi" />ghi<br />                            
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pvc" name="pvc" value="jkl" />jkl<br />
                        <input type="checkbox" id="pvc" name="pvc" value="NONE" />NONE<br />
                </td>           
            </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#addTechDetails")
                    .button()
                    .click(function(){

                        var pvc = $("#input[ type= 'checkbox']");
                        var pvcData = [];
                        pvc.filter(':checked').each(function(){
                            pvcData.push($(this).val());
                        })
                        pvc=pvcData.join(',');

                        //initial info required to process form
                        var newOrExisting = $("#newOrExisting").val();      
                        var numCircuits = $("#numCircuits").val();          

                            var str = "newOrExisting="+newOrExisting+"&numCircuits="+numCircuits+"&pvc="+pvc;

                                     //ajax request
                            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                cache : false,
                                url : "ajax/addTechDetails.php",
                                data : str,
                                complete : function(xhr, result){
                                    if (result != "success") return;
                                    var response = xhr.responseText;                                    
                                    $("#result").html(response);
                                }
                            })
            });
```

output of above is the following even when some selections are checked:  '','','','',

Comment: You have no elements with the ID `#newOrExisting` or `#numCircuits`, so how do you expect to get a value? All the checkboxes have the same ID, and that's an error!

Comment: off the top of my head, the name attribute of the checkboxes should be `pvc[]`, not just `pvc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checkboxes need unique ID's:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pvc1" name="pvc" value="abc" />
<input type="checkbox" id="pvc2" name="pvc" value="def" />
...
```

Also, this line `var pvc = $("#input[ type= 'checkbox']");` should not include a leading `#` since this is used to identify by Id (and `input` is not an Id).

You could use one of the following methods:

- `$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each()` Iterates all checked elements
- `$('input[name="pvc"]:checked').each()` Iterates all checkboxes by name
- `$('#pvc'+indexOfiteration).val()` Gets value directly from Id

There are more options in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a # at the start of the input selector. That is an id selector. You should just have input[type='checkbox']

.. and as stated above, the checkboxes cannot have the same id.